Django Internationalization test error:Couldn't retrieve redirection page
I wrote a blog project in Django,in some pages i used loginrequierdmixin to make sure user is loged in but in test i got error
test:
    def test_get_profile_unauthenticated(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.profile_url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        expected_url = f"{self.register_url}?next={self.profile_url}"
        self.assertRedirects(response, expected_url)

AssertionError: 302 != 200 : Couldn't retrieve redirection page '/accounts/register/': response code was 302 (expected 200)

i print response:
<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/accounts/register/?next=/en/accounts/profile/1/">

and my exepted url:
/en/accounts/register/?next=/en/accounts/profile/1/

i asked chatGPT and here is response:
    def test_get_profile_unauthenticated(self):
        self.client.cookies.clear()
        with translation.override('en'):
            response = self.client.get(self.profile_url, HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE='en')
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
            expected_url = f"{self.register_url}?next={self.profile_url}"
            self.assertRedirects(response, expected_url)

